# How to vaildate jtextfield in java swing float value upto two field using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextfield

I have try many thing available on the internet but do not find the suitable one

Comment: Hi, welcome SO. Please share what you tried and tell us what didn't work, why, what was the expected behaviour and what happened instead.

Comment: I suggest to get familiar with this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html This tutorial will show you how to deal with custom formatters.

Comment: I am designing a calculator in whcih i have jtextfield and i want to allow value or real number or fraction number but upto two decimal point and hence result will be shown by maximum two decimal point...

Answer (score 1):

> ..float value..

Immediately suggests a `JSpinner` with an appropriate `SpinnerNumberModel` to me. E.G.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class FloatSpinner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SpinnerNumberModel floatModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(
                        2.14f, 0f, 3f, .01f);
                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(floatModel);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, spinner);
                System.out.println(
                        "User Chose: " + floatModel.getNumber().floatValue());
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to add this with jtextfield1